# JSON parsing issue with Gujarati font in Android text view

Tags: java, android, json, android-fonts

I have developed an application, that has text view for display some Gujarati text from the JSON URL and data stored in PHP MySQL server database.

So, problem with display Gujarati font:
[image]

My code of JSON http is here:

```
public class CustomHttpClient {

 
    public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; 
 
    private static HttpClient mHttpClient;


 

 private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {

  if (mHttpClient == null) {
   mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   
   final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
   HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
   HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
   ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
  }

  return mHttpClient;
 }
 
public static String executeHttpPost(String url,ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader in = null;

      try {
    
       HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
    
       HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    
       UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
       postParameters);
    
       request.setEntity(formEntity);
    
       HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    
       in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
       .getContent()));
      
       
    //   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8000);
       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    
       String line = "";
    
       String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    
       while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    
       sb.append(line + NL);
    
       }
    
       in.close();
       String result = sb.toString();
       return result;
    
      } finally {

   if (in != null) {

    try {

     in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

     Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString()); 

     e.printStackTrace();

    }

   }

  }

 }
```

and main activity code here:

```
desc_about=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textdesc);

Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"Shruti.ttf");
       desc_about.setTypeface(tf);

ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("temple_id","2"));



String response = null;
          
          try {             
                        response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
                        url_temple,postParameters);
                      
                        String result = response.toString();  
  
         try {
                 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                 for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
                 {
                     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     about_temple=json_data.getString("about_text");
          }
      
         }
         catch(JSONException e){
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
         }

 }
     
         try{
           
           
           desc_about.setText(about_temple);
           
           
         }
         catch(Exception e){
          Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error" + 2, 100).show();
         }   
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error" + 3, 100).show();
    }
```

Comment: use this line : new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"), 8);

Comment: getting error null pointer Exception

Answer (score 0):

Try using utf-endcoding at the time of making JSON on php side and same way decode utf in android side. I solved it using this way in iOS app, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,"http://floming.com/shayri/guj_romanse.json", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            String str = "";
            try {
                str = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String decodedStr = Html.fromHtml(str).toString();
```